# Selecting from two tables and a where condition

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
Images:
id | name | width

Extra:
id | width | extra
```

How can I select all from images and for each row, select 'extra' from the extra table where images.width is <= extra.width?

E.g.

```
Images:
id | name | width
1  | a.jpg| 100
2  | b.jpg| 200
3  | c.jpg| 5
Extra:
id | width | extra
1  | 100   | 'test'
2  | 200   | 'normal'
3  | 50    | 'better'
```

So:

- a.jpg would have an extra of 'test'.
- b.jpg would have an extra of
  'normal'.
- c.jpg would have an extra of 'better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT *
FROM Images JOIN Extra ON Images.width<=Extra.width
```

Comment: Thanks but wouldn't this return multiple rows for items such as c.jpg? I only need one row, the one that is closet to the width, so c.jpg is less than 50, 100 and 200 but I just need the 50 row.